# How to get a polynomial providing the exponential numbers for each term of the function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, polynomials

I'm trying to write a polynomial. However, I have found scipy methods which give the polynomial format like x^4 + 2x^3 - x^2 + 3, from which the coefficients are [3, 0, -1, 2, 1], and the exponential by 4, 3, and 2.

Is there a way to manipulate the exponential through a given list of number? Something like, giving:

```
nj = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

For example, I could calculate terms of a polynomial like `coef*x^nj = 0` for a given unique coef.

Thank you!

Comment: Polynomial construction is described in this tutorial: https://www.python-course.eu/polynomial_class_in_python.php

Comment: Thank you @Piinthesky, it seems a nice tutorial. I'll have a look.

Comment: @CrazyIvan it means just that the exponential numbers from the polynomial are provided from a list. For example, if my list is given by nj, my polynomial would be:

coef*x^0 + coef*x^1.0 + coef*x^2.0 + coef*x^2.0 + (...and so on) + coef*x^7.0 + coef*x^8.0 = 0

See that some exmponential numbers are repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a NumPy array of coefficients `coef`, and a NumPy array of exponents `nj`, the value of the polynomial at `x` can be computed as

```
coef.dot(x**nj)
```

Example:

```
coef = np.array([3.1, 0, -2, 5, 1.1])
nj = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 5])   
x = 1.23
print(coef.dot(x**nj))   # 10.7355362527
```